# Calculate new coordinate based on distance traveled between two other coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, java, latitude-longitude

We have two coordinates (latitude, longitude) and let's assume we want to travel along a straight line between them. After traveling a certain distance along this line, we would like to calculate a new coordinate for this location. How can this be done?

```
Point startCoord = new Point(52.515343254180486, 13.384435940499088);
Point endCoord = new Point(52.51544771840784, 13.386055994744083);
double totalDistance = 110.23868303918874; // in meters
double intervalDistance = 50; // in meters
```

*Note: Distances between points will always be fairly small.*

**Possible solution:**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738281/1105939) post we can find the `angle` between `startCoord` and `endCoord`.

Using the `intervalDistance` as hypotenuse, we can find x and y distances away from the `startCoord` using simple trig:

```
double dx = intervalDistance * Math.sin(angle);
double dy = intervalDistance * Math.cos(angle);
```

And based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478827/1105939) post, we can calculate the new coordinate based on the x and y distance away (in meters) from the `startCoord`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually both of the [Geodetic Problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems), used serially.

First you solve the Inverse (aka Reverse) problem, to obtain distance and bearing from two points, then you use the Forward (aka Direct) problem to travel distance and bearing from the first point.

I'd recommend you find a library that implements these functions, but it's certainly possible to port the [US National Geodetic Survey FORTRAN code](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/) to Java yourself (I did, long ago, first to 'C' then to Java, but NGS has tweaked the code since then).

Comment: Thank you for defining the problem more formally

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer from Vince, this is fairly easy with a library.

The [Geodesic](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/net/sf/geographiclib/Geodesic.html) class from the [geographiclib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/) library provides a great implementation for Java (other language implementations are also available):

```
GeodesicData g1 = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(52.515343254180486, 13.384435940499088, 52.51544771840784, 13.386055994744083);
GeodesicData g2 = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(g1.lat1, g1.lon1, g1.azi1, 50.0d);
System.out.println(g2.lat2 + ", " + g2.lon2); // 52.51539048629184, 13.385168382935976
```