# Break a bounding box into smaller boxes (coordinates)

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, boundaries

My objective is to create a collection of bounding box coordinates that I can supply to a search function. The idea is that I have the search function search smaller geographic areas, instead of one large one.

To achieve this, I would like to develop some function that takes the following inputs:

- Overall bounding box (to be divided) (4 lat/lng points)
- Area of smaller bounding box

Are there any tools that I could use to do this?

The output should be a collection of sets (each has 4 points) representing bounding boxes that are inside the overall (parent) bounding box.

I am happy to write a tool using any language or alternatively use an intuitive web based tool.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I am in the process of figuring this out using simple functions that calculate the distance between two points, but writing here for sanity check also.

Comment: you trying to split the bbox in a number of smaller bboxes (which would mean adding or subtracting)? or how you pretend to multiply times the "area of smaller bounding box" (which would make a centered bbox)?

Comment: The best way to write a function to solve the geodetic Inverse problem is to use an existing one.  Partial differential equations aren't fun to solve.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333407/calculate-new-coordinate-based-on-distance-traveled-between-two-other-coordinate

Comment: I made these polygons out of larger ones, which comprised 4 of these (that's the way the mexican authority divides the country), I may share the code with you if you think this is what you want,  https://pronaturaveracruz.org/lidars/